# Replace strings with numbers in the dataframe for clustering python

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning, cluster-analysis

I have a CSV file like this:
[image]
I read this file in python and put it into a variable, but to use it for machine learning, I need to convert these strings into numbers.

How can I convert something like "Cold" in the column "ord_2" to the integer 1 (in python)?

I am a newbie please don't be too hard.
any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use a dictionary and define *integers* as your "key" and *strings* as your "value". then you can use the key for your purpose and the values for having the string.also you can define the *strings* as your "key" and *numbers* as your "value" and call them.

I didn't try it myself, but maybe works or give you a clue.